# how to hide a tab in sj:tabbedpanel

Tags: jquery, struts2

i'm using the struts2-jquery tabbed panel widget. I am displaying the tabs without issues. Now  I want to hide some of them for some users. I am using $(document).ready jquery but when the page loads, the whole page is not showing. Can anyone help on which jquery to use?

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#remotetabs > ul").tabs("remove", 2);

});
```

Here is my tabbedpanel:

```
<sj:tabbedpanel id="remotetabs" useSelectedTabCookie="false" >
        <sj:tab id="tab1" href="%{urlHome}" label="tab1" />
        <sj:tab id="tab2" href="%{urlSearch}" label="tab2"  />
        <sj:tab id="tab3" href="%{urlReport}" label="tab3"  />
</sj:tabbedpanel>
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: `$("#tab3").hide();` ?

Comment: hi Andrea...that didn't work..thanks anyway..

Comment: Then you are not using id="tab3", or you have other javascript problems.

Comment: To try it go [on the showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action), with Firefox, press Widgets -> Tabs -> Remote Tabs with Topics, press CTRL+SHIFT+K, then write `$("#tab2").toggle();` enter, press up, enter, press up, enter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide a tab:

```
$("#tab3").hide();
```

To show a tab:

```
$("#tab3").show();
```

To change its state (hide if shown, show if hidden):

```
$("#tab3").toggle();
```

The above code is suitable for every kind of object (with an id) in your page, or changing the selector, to any object.

But this will only `hide` the object from the page; if you need to not show that object to that particular user, you should perform the control serverside, without even posting the "top secret" tab...

Comment: hi Andrea..you are right, some problem with my javascript. It is now hiding my tabs. thanks very much.